# Non qualified retirement account

Tags: united-states, retirement-plan

I have a non qualified retirement account with the company.  The company was sold to another company and the new owner decided to terminate the non qualified retirement plan and pay me the lump sum.  So my understanding is I will have to pay income tax for the whole amount.  Is there anyway I can roll it over to an retirement account?  Is there any penalty for this early withdrawal even though it's not my intention?

Comment: Can you edit and add country tag.

Comment: Ok, I added the country tag.

Answer (score 2):

I asked Google.  It found me the article http://finance.zacks.com/can-nonqualified-plan-proceeds-rolled-ira-10526.html

Read this snippet:

> Qualified Plans
>
> A qualified plan meets the standards of the Employee Retirement Income Security Act and provides tax benefits to plan members. You can roll any of the following plan types to an IRA: a traditional IRA, an employer's qualified retirement plan such as a 401(k), a qualified trust, a deferred-compensation plan such as a 457, or a tax-sheltered annuity plan such as a 403(b). You can't roll over nonqualified plans such as 409A deferred-compensation plans, executive bonus plans, group carve-out plans or split-dollar life insurance plans.